# change text written in english into hindi wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to change the text written in english into hindi inside my search bar,
i am developing a hindi newspaper website by using wordpress cms so when user type in english to search related news in search bar that text should change in hindi because all the news in written in hindi so searching news become easy.please help me if somebody know. 
here is my wordpress by default search code:

```
<section class="search_main">
       <div class="search_box">
           <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">  
              <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar eng my_control" name="s" id="search" placeholder="search....." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn my-btn"  id="searchsubmit"  type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                      </span>
              </div><!--input group-->

              </form> 
       </div><!--search box-->

       </section><!--search main-->
```

Comment: you could try posting this question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/  That's a dedicated Q&A website for wordpress..

Comment: hi lucy,  thanks for suggestion i too posted this in wordpress community but you know response is little late over there.